# How to use javascript(Angular.js) with laravel get php url(asset)

Tags: php, laravel, url

I use javascript(Angular.js) with laravel

```
<aside data-ng-include=" {{ asset('layout/nav') }} " id="nav-container"></aside>
```

but is error:NotFoundHttpException load no path,

What can be read into the .php file？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im a little confused on what you are trying to do, but it seems that you are using asset() to link a directory. I would use the laravel function link_to() instead, since it is made to generate links to paths.

Here is the link to the laravel documentation with more information on link_to() and asset():

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls

Comment: thank you,  I use laravel 5.1 , is not link_to() function, But the 5.1 document, there are other ways, so I'm trying to test~!